# Parsing time from Python to Html

Tags: python, html, raspberry-pi

I need help showing a variable from Python in Html.
Is it possible to pass the current time from Python with every frame to the Html with blocking the video stream?

I need it to verify that the video stream is alive on a Raspberry Pi running Windows IoT Core.

I have tried with the time coming from Html, but that doesn’t work because the time continues even when the stream has stopped.

Tia,
Henrik

My Python script

```
from threading import Condition
from http import server

import datetime
timenow = datetime.datetime.now()
print(timenow)

PAGE="""\
<html>
<head>
<title>picamera MJPEG streaming demo </title>
</head>
<body onload="startTime()" bgcolor="#000000">
<img src="stream.mjpg" width="480" height="270"/>
<p>{timenow}</p>
</body>
</html>
"""

class StreamingOutput(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.frame = None
    self.buffer = io.BytesIO()
    self.condition = Condition()

def write(self, buf):
    if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
        # New frame, copy the existing buffer's content and notify all
        # clients it's available
        self.buffer.truncate()
        with self.condition:
            self.frame = self.buffer.getvalue()
            self.condition.notify_all()
        self.buffer.seek(0)
    return self.buffer.write(buf)


class StreamingHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
def do_GET(self):
    if self.path == '/':
        self.send_response(301)
        self.send_header('Location', '/index.html')
        self.end_headers()
    elif self.path == '/index.html':
        content = PAGE.encode('utf-8')
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.send_header('Content-Length', len(content))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(content)
    elif self.path == '/stream.mjpg':
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Age', 0)
        self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private')
        self.send_header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=FRAME')
        self.end_headers()

       # print(now)

        try:
            while True:
                with output.condition:
                    output.condition.wait()
                    frame = output.frame
                self.wfile.write(b'--FRAME\r\n')
                self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                self.send_header('Content-Length', len(frame))
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(frame)
                self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')

        except Exception as e:
            logging.warning(
                'Removed streaming client %s: %s',
                self.client_address, str(e))
    else:
        self.send_error(404)
        self.end_headers()

class StreamingServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, server.HTTPServer):
allow_reuse_address = True
daemon_threads = True

with picamera.PiCamera(resolution='480x270', framerate=12) as camera:
output = StreamingOutput()
camera.rotation=180
camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
try:
    address = ('', 8000)
    server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
    server.serve_forever()


finally:
    camera.stop_recording()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were basically doing it only once, at the beginning of the script, and when you execute the script to run the server you basically evaluate `datetime.now()` only once, instead what you need to do is evaluate if for every `GET` request.

In order to add it to the stream response itself, since it is a `multipart` you can just add another response section with the

```
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: ... what ever the length of the time string is
```

and then just add a `json` dump string of the timenow like this: `json.dumps( { "timenow": str(datetime.datetime.now()) } )` and then you have to parse the JSON response of the additional multipart section on the frontend.

```
def do_GET(self):
    if self.path == '/':
        ...
    elif self.path == '/index.html':
        timenow = datetime.datetime.now()
        content = PAGE.format(timenow=timenow).encode('utf-8')
        ... the rest of the code
    elif self.path == '/stream.mjpg':
        ...
        try:
            while True:
                with output.condition:
                    output.condition.wait()
                    frame = output.frame

                # add the frame
                self.wfile.write(b'--FRAME\r\n')
                self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                self.send_header('Content-Length', len(frame))
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(frame)
                self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')

                # add the time information
                timenow = str(datetime.datetime.now())
                self.wfile.write(b'--TIME\r\n')
                self.send_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                self.send_header('Content-Length' len(timenow)), 
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(json.dumps({"timenow": timenow}).encode('utf-8))
                self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')

        except Exception as e:
            logging.warning(
                'Removed streaming client %s: %s',
                self.client_address, str(e))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Unfortunately, it still doesn’t return the current time.
When looking at the webpage in developer tools I can see it returns <p>{timenow}</p>
Is my html correct?

Comment: @henrikl2000 that is not possible, it doesn't have anything to do with your HTML. I've used exactly your code in my console and the `{timenow}` gets replaced with what I specified in the `format` call for the `timenow` argument. Did you do `content = PAGE.format(timenow=timenow).encode()` and send the content in the response, or did you not use it?

Comment: Yes I am using Python 3

Comment: Try deleting the .pyc file associated with it, maybe it's still using the old bytecode, and make sure you save the script !

Comment: This is what I changed
def do_GET(self):
        timenow = datetime.datetime.now()
        PAGE.format(timenow=timenow).encode()

I am sorry I am a newbee in Python what is a .pyc file?
I am using Python Idle if it makes any difference

Comment: @henrikl2000 also, I don't know what you are doing on the frontend side, it just struck my mind that perhaps you are requesting the `/index.html` only once, and you are actually making multiple requests to `/stream.mjpg` in which case you should be attaching the timenow information to that response. Am I correct?

Comment: @henrikl2000 ah from what I'm getting from your comment you are not saving the formatted PAGE anywhere, look at my answer again, I have edited it.

Comment: In Windows IoT Core I am using a WebView to view the stream from the Raspberry Pi with the connected camera. The WebView works like a browser. My problem is that the WebView sometimes freezes and that is why I need the time to compare that the stream is alive. Yes I think it is the index.html How can I attach the timenow to the stream.mjpg ?

Comment: Correct the file is not saved

Comment: Thank's a lot Andrew that did the trick. Now I get the time on refresh of the page.
It was really nice of you to help me out here. Again thank you

Comment: @henrikl2000 to add it to the `/stream.mjpg` you need to specify another multipart section. See my answer again on how to add the timenow as part of the stream response. I think you could theoretically add the timenow as like a json response, but I'm not sure if you can parse that on the frontend. Let me know how it worked for you, and please vote the answer if it is the right one!

Comment: Now in the Python Shell I get an error WARNING:root:Removed streaming client ('192.168.0.100', 50367): name 'json' is not defined

Comment: @henrikl2000 you need to import the json package at the top of the script.

Comment: Yes of cause, but I still get an error "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: @henrikl2000 ah yes sorry for that, instead of `json.dumps({"timenow": timenow})` do `json.dumps({"timenow": timenow}).encode('utf-8)` .. I forgot the encoding.

Comment: Now the error is gone but the stream freezes after one video frame
I am sorry I am such a pain … but I am used to VB.Net and completely on the ice in Python

Comment: @henrikl2000 are you parsing the --TIME section in VB.NET ?
Put some prints in the python script  to see if it hangs somewhere, put the timenow in the print so you see that it updates constantly. like `print(timenow)`

Comment: I added a print(timenow) in the end of the time section. When I go to http://192.168.0.xx:8000 in Edge the Python shell start to update the time rapidly, but the video stream is still frozen. So the time section works, but is interrupting with the video section I think

Comment: @henrikl2000 you'll have to figure out from here, I helped as much as I could. Please vote this answer if it helped you in the end.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. It helped at lot